# Can we connect to Sybase Database from Python on Linux server without FreeTDS installed?

Tags: python, linux, database, sqlanywhere, sybase-asa

I am currently working on a Linux Server where I need to write a Python Script to parse an XML and store it in a Sybase based Database. When I started looking for available Libraries I found out that most of them have a dependency on FreeTDS.

Since my organization is very reluctant to get new tools installed I am looking if there is an alternate way to connect to Sybase Database from Python on my Linux Server. Thanks in advance.

Comment: which Sybase RDBMS product (ASE? SQLAnywhere? IQ? Advantage?) and version?

Comment: I am using SQLAnywhere. I am not sure how to check for the version.